# Receiving MouseMove events from parent control

Tags: c#, winforms, mousemove

I have a WinForm application that has a panel and two buttons inside the panel. I added a mousemove event on my panel and the mousemove function gets called when I move the mouse inside my panel, just like expected.

The problem is, if I press down my mouse button while over a button, the button depresses and if I move my mouse into the panel while still holding down the button, the Panel mousemove function never gets called till I release the mouse button.

Is there a work around for this? And if I'm not being clear, I can try to be more clear.

Comment: you mean even if the user press the mouse and holds on the button, the panel should move?

Comment: I'm not trying to move anything. I'm just trying to make the panel's MouseMove event fire. Since I'm moving the mouse inside the panel, the expected behavior would be that the MouseMove event should fire

Comment: Give the `MouseMove` event of the panel to `MouseDown` event of the button?

Comment: I did, but what I'm saying is that if the button is pushed down and the mouse moved, the MouseMove event will not fire

Comment: Give some Boolean, something like, if MouseDown of button then that boolean will be `true` and then invoke MouseMove event of button which will fire MouseMove event of the Panel. and again on MouseUp of the Button, the boolean will become false.

Comment: Are you saying to do something like subscribe to MouseMove of button, then inside that function call parent.MouseMove()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that while the button is depressed and the mouse moved back over the underlying panel, the panel's MouseMove event is not fired.

You can capture the pointer position at this time by hooking into the button's MouseMove.  BUT, the pointer's position will be relative to the button, not the panel, so you need to add these coordinates to the button's location coordinate:

```
Point mousePoint;

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mousePoint = e.Location;
}

private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mousePoint = new Point(button1.Location.X + e.Location.X, button1.Location.Y + e.Location.Y);
}
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion. That seems kooky though that the panel just can't simply fire the mousemove event